# Verifiying app server communication?

Tags: android, client-server, verification

I have an android app that sends http POST requests to a server in order to modify data. In this request, a user and device ID is sent in order to verify that the user is indeed using the device they logged in on.

However, this means that anyone with someones device ID and their user ID can send a request and modify data.

How should I go about making the communication more secure and add verification that the request is from my app?

I can't just add random headers with static values to it, as headers can easily be added to cURL request.

Answer (score 0):

Implement OAuth  in your server and generate a consumer key and Secret(App Specific), which is unique for your app and using the consumer key and secret your app will generate a request token first and it will exchange the request token for an Access token. 
 Now you can access the protected resources.

There are libraries to make this process easier , you can check the client side and server side libraries in this link https://oauth.net/code/#client-libraries

OAuth1.0a https://oauth.net/core/1.0a/

(latest)OAuth 2.0 https://oauth.net/2/